# jquery show/hide being ignored

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page where a user can 'like' an article.

When the page first loads I want to show if they've already liked an article.

The code I'm using to add html to the DOM is:

```
html += '<div class="gl_like">';
html += '<a href="#" class="like" id="'+image.article_id+'"><div class="bLike" title="Like this article"></div></a>';
html += '<a href="#" class="unlike" id="'+image.article_id+'"><div class="bUnlike" title="Unlike this article"></div></a>';
html += '</div>';
```

Now I'm checking what the API throws back as to whether a user has already liked an article

```
if(image.numLikes<1){
$('.like').show();
$('.unlike').hide();
html += 'wooo'; // to test the code works, it does
} else {
$('.like').hide();
$('.unlike').show();
}
```

The "wooo" is added to the html but the show/hide functions are being ignored. The ".like" class is shown on every article.

What I want to happen is the ".like" class shows if user hasn't liked an article and ".unlike" class shows if they have.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: you need to run the if statement after the HTML is added to the DOM

Comment: Are you getting both `like` and `unlike` always?

Comment: @ManseUK there might be 15 articles on a page, the html is loaded from a for loop, therefire cannot be run after added to html

Comment: Do you really want to show/hide *all* `.like`/`.unlike` elements?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Your selectors are only searching for elements attached to the `document`. If they're only described by your `html` variable as a string of markup, they won't be found. So, you'll have to rethink your approach. Also, your selectors will find *every* element in the `document` with a `class` of `like` or `unlike`, not just the most recently added, and `hide`/`show` all of them the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it guys, thanks:

```
if(image.numLikes<1){
    html += '<a href="#" class="like" id="'+image.article_id+'"><div class="bLike" title="Like this article"></div></a>';
    html += '<a href="#" class="unlike" id="'+image.article_id+'" style="display:none;"><div class="bUnlike" title="Unlike this article"></div></a>';
    } else {
    html += '<a href="#" class="like" id="'+image.article_id+'" style="display:none;"><div class="bLike" title="Like this article"></div></a>';
    html += '<a href="#" class="unlike" id="'+image.article_id+'"><div class="bUnlike" title="Unlike this article"></div></a>';
    }
```

Instead of using show/hide its easier to literally show or hide.

Not sure I explained the question very well either, apologies for that but thanks a bunch for the answers.

Answer (score 2):

Do you add the html to DOM anywhere?

If not, try this:

```
$(html).find('.like').show();
$(html).find('.unlike').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're creating elements with duplicate id attributes: id="'+image.article_id+'"
You'll need to change this so that they are unique which is required. ex:

```
html += '<div class="gl_like">';
html += '<a href="#" class="like" id="like_'+image.article_id+'"><div class="bLike" title="Like this article"></div></a>';
html += '<a href="#" class="unlike" id="unlike_'+image.article_id+'"><div class="bUnlike" title="Unlike this article"></div></a>';
html += '</div>';
```

Comment: @DarrenSweeney According to your code sample, they both use ID=image.article_id

Comment: Actually, in your example you are doing duplicate IDs. That isn't probably your issue you are asking about in this question, but it is wrong.